# Java Inheritance - C -> B -> A. Method defined in A and overriden in C. Which one should be called?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, default

I have a base **interface A**. Then there is another **interface B which extends from this interface A**. And finally a **class C which implements B**.

```
interface A{
    default void method1(){
        System.out.println("method1 printing from interface A");
    }
    default void method2(){
         method1(); // note that method1() is overriden in class C.
                    // which one should be called? from A or C?
    }
}

interface B extends A{
    void methodWhichCallsMethodOnInterface();
}

class C implements B{
    @Override 
    public void method1(){
        System.out.println("method1 printing from class C");
    }

    @Override
    public void methodWhichCallsMethodOnInterface(){
        method2();
    }
}
```

I am calling methodWhichCallsMethodOnInterface in this way:

```
B b = new C();
b.methodWhichCallsMethodOnInterface();
```

The output is "method1 printing from class C".

I dont understand how method1 from C is getting called directly from the interface A? Can someone explain the contexts in which each method is called?

Comment: Given your example, what does `C` have to do with it?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/SkuZHS). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The code you provide shouldn't do anything at all.  Are you sure you're showing us the right code?  You can't directly instantiate an instance of B, because B is an interface (which is abstract).  So, at best, all the code could produce is a NullPointerException, but it likely doesn't even compile.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz B doesnt have an implementation for methodWhichCallsMethodOnInterface. It is overriden in C which gets called when I do b.methodWhichCallsMethodOnInterface();

Comment: Your code just prints `"method1 printing from class C"` like it should

Comment: *I dont understand how method1 from C is getting called directly from the interface A?* That's just how overriding works. The implementation is selected based on the runtime type of `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `b.methodWhichCallsMethodOnInterface()` calls `method2()` from interface A and `method2()` from interface A calls `method2()` from interface A, I assume you thought `b.methodWhichCallsMethodOnInterface()` would for some reason make `method2()` from interface A call `method1()` from class C.

If you call `b.method1()` you should get printing from class C
But calling the other function will call interface A's `method1()`

I assume you intialized `B b = new C()` right?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `interface B` extend `interface A` so you can imagine that:

```
interface B {
    default void method1() { // inherited from A
        System.out.println("method1 printing from interface A");
    }

    default void method2() { // inherited from A
        method1();
    }

    void methodWhichCallsMethodOnInterface(); // wrote new in B
}
```

You can forget the `interface A` from now! Continue with your code.

```
class C implements B{
    @Override 
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("method1 printing from class C");
    }

    @Override
    public void methodWhichCallsMethodOnInterface() {
        method2();
    } 
}
```

`Class B` was implemented by `class C`. When you execute the code `B b = new C`, an object C will be created and cast to `interface B` (it mean `object b` have full properties of `class C`). Look at the `interface B` and `class C`, you can see two same methods `method1()`. Because `class C` implement `interface B` and `method1()` is overwritten, so `b.method1()` will execute the method inside `class C`. You can imagine that:

```
class C implements B{
    @Override 
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("method1 printing from class C");
    }

    @Override
    public void methodWhichCallsMethodOnInterface() {
        method2();
    }

    default void method2() { // inherited from B
        method1();
    }
}
```

Now, I think you can understand why your program print `method1 printing from class C`.

Answer (score -4):

It's correctly calling the method1() of A because it's the method of interface. That's the correct & expected behavior of methods defined in interface.